# How to decode raw_outputs/box_encodings from Tensorflow Object detection ssd-mobilenet without nms

Tags: object, tensorflow, detection

In order to deploy my own ssd-mobile model on android and use `NNAPI` acceleration  , I retrained the model without NMS post processing according to the `tensorflow objection detection API`.
   without NMS, the output `raw_outputs/box_encodings` are encoded box location, I decode it as follows, but it does not work:

```
for(int j =0; j < 5; j++)
               {
                   float sk = (float)(0.2 + (0.949 - 0.200) *j * 1.0 / 5*1.0);
                   float width_a = (float)(sk * Math.sqrt(aspectra[j]));
                   float height_a = (float)(sk * 1.0 / Math.sqrt(aspectra[j]));
                   for(int k = 0; k < featuresize[j] ; k++)
                   {
                       float center_x_a = (float)((k + 0.5) * 1.0/ featuresize[j]);
                       float center_y_a = (float)((k + 0.5) * 1.0/ featuresize[j]);

                       float ty = (float)(outputBox[0][i][0] / 10.);
                       float tx = (float)(outputBox[0][i][1] /  10.);
                       float th = (float)(outputBox[0][i][2] / 5.);
                       float tw = (float)(outputBox[0][i][3] / 5.);

                       float w =(float)(Math.exp(tw) * width_a);
                       float h = (float)(Math.exp(th) * height_a);
                       float y_center = ty * height_a + center_y_a;
                       float x_ceneter = tx * width_a + center_x_a;


                       float ymin = (float)((y_center - h ) / 2.);
                       float xmin = (float)((x_ceneter - w ) / 2.);
                       float ymax = (float)((y_center + h ) / 2.);
                       float xmax = (float)((x_ceneter + w ) / 2.);
```

Answer (score 6):

In order to decode `raw_outputs/box_encodings` you also need `anchors` as the box_encodings are encoded with respect to anchors.

Following is my implementation of decoding `raw_outputs/box_encodings`:

```
private float[][][] decodeBoxEncodings(final float[][][] boxEncoding, final float[][] anchor, final int numBoxes) {
    final float[][][] decodedBoxes = new float[1][numBoxes][4];
    for (int i = 0; i < numBoxes; ++i) {

        final double ycenter = boxEncoding[0][i][0] / y_scale * anchor[i][2] + anchor[i][0];
        final double xcenter = boxEncoding[0][i][1] / x_scale * anchor[i][3] + anchor[i][1];
        final double half_h = 0.5 * Math.exp((boxEncoding[0][i][2] / h_scale)) * anchor[i][2];
        final double half_w = 0.5 * Math.exp((boxEncoding[0][i][3] / w_scale)) * anchor[i][3];

        decodedBoxes[0][i][0] = (float)(ycenter - half_h);   //ymin
        decodedBoxes[0][i][1] = (float)(xcenter - half_w);   //xmin
        decodedBoxes[0][i][2] = (float)(ycenter + half_h);   //ymax
        decodedBoxes[0][i][3] = (float)(xcenter + half_w);   //xmax
    }
    return decodedBoxes;
}
```

This decoding technique is from TFLite [detection_postprocess](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/kernels/detection_postprocess.cc) operation.

Edit: scale values are:

```
float y_scale = 10.0f;
float x_scale = 10.0f;
float h_scale = 5.0f;
float w_scale = 5.0f;
```

Answer (score 0):

https://actcast.hatenablog.com/entry/2021/08/06/085134

This worked for me.

My pb model - SSD Mobilenet V1 0.75 Depth Quantized (tflite_graph.pb)
Tf Version - 1.15
outputs - raw_outputs/box_encodings & raw_outputs/class_predictions

1. Start from the step 3 (Create Anchor) steps in the above mentioned blog (as the model ready was ready with me, I didn't do training part)
2. 4th step is not required if model ready & load our model (they have
   loaded nnoir_model, instead of that we can load our model)

corresponding google colabs : https://colab.research.google.com/github/Idein/tensorflow-object-detection-api-to-nnoir/blob/master/notebook/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2018_01_28_to_nnoir.ipynb#scrollTo=51d0jACEslWu